# Unknwown data type

Tags: php

I can't find out how it works .. 
Is that like json ?

```
a:1:{s:6:"editor";s:1:"1";}
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

Comment: Is that SQL, is my question?

Comment: Probably not. It seems to be a way to store data ...

Comment: Perjhaps more details about wht you are trying to do and what exact error message you are getting would help. Provided code is not SQL in any form I have  ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string that you have appears to be a serialized PHP array. You can expand it by running `unserialize` on it, as follows:

```
$input = 'a:1:{s:6:"editor";s:1:"1";}';
$output = unserialize($input);
var_dump($output);
```

As you can see, this will print out an array:

```
array(1) {
  ["editor"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

You can also call `json_encode` on that $output, which will return a JSON string.

```
$input = 'a:1:{s:6:"editor";s:1:"1";}';
$output = unserialize($input);
echo json_encode($output);
// Prints '{"editor":"1"}'
```